# Why I get randomly "Failed to mount Windows share: Connection timed out" with VPN connection?

Tags: networking, 13.10, vpn, file-sharing, shared-folders

In **Ubuntu 13.10** (everything is up-to-date) I get randomly this error popup message, during working with shared folders using a VPN connection over the internet:

**Unhandled error message: Failed to mount Windows share: Connection timed out**

Effect: Working with shared folders is not working anymore / sometimes it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting "Failed to mount windows share: Connection timed out" when trying to connect from an Ubuntu guest (in VMWare) to Windows 7 host (the physical machine). I could ping the machine, but not reach the shared folder.  I changed the vmware network settings from 'bridged' to 'host only' (didn't work) and then to 'nat' and that worked. Each time you change these settings Ubuntu sees a network disconnect and then re-connect, and I suppose it is assigned a new IP address in the process.

Comment: Ok thnx for the info. I have not been receiving the error message for a couple month. Maybe some system update fixed the problem. If the error should occur once more, I will try to get some more information via the log, as mentioned here: http://askubuntu.com/a/252103/175489